# Find the last actual reported quarter

Tags: c#, json.net, linq-to-json

I'm trying to find the last actual reported quarter and it's accompanying display value.  The criteria is the @clientsDescription or @displayName has to EPS.  Here's what my JSON string looks like:

```
{
    "?xml": {
        "@version": "1.0",
        "@encoding": "UTF-8"
    },
    "DataFeed": {
        "@FeedName": "issuerDetails",
        "SecurityDetails": {
            "Security": {
                "@sequence": "850",
                "TimesSeriesList": [{
                        "@description": "EPS",
                        "@clientsDescription": "EPS",
                        "FinancialValue": [{
                                "@displayRank": "850",
                                "@estimateActual": "Actual",
                                "@period": "Q1",
                                "@periodEnd": "2015-9-30T00:00:00.00",
                                "@displayName": "EPS",
                                "CurrentValue": {
                                    "@displayValue": "$0.19"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "@displayRank": "850",
                                "@estimateActual": "Actual",
                                "@period": "Q2",
                                "@periodEnd": "2015-12-31T00:00:00.00",
                                "@displayName": "EPS",
                                "CurrentValue": {
                                    "@displayValue": "$0.26"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "@displayRank": "850",
                                "@estimateActual": "Actual",
                                "@period": "Q3",
                                "@periodEnd": "2015-3-31T00:00:00.00",
                                "@displayName": "EPS",
                                "CurrentValue": {
                                    "@displayValue": "$0.34"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "@displayRank": "850",
                                "@estimateActual": "Estimate",
                                "@period": "Q4",
                                "@periodEnd": "2015-6-30T00:00:00.00",
                                "@displayName": "EPS",
                                "CurrentValue": {
                                    "@displayValue": "$0.32"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "@displayRank": "850",
                                "@estimateActual": "Estimate",
                                "@period": "Annual",
                                "@periodEnd": "2015-6-30T00:00:00.00",
                                "@displayName": "EPS",
                                "CurrentValue": {
                                    "@displayValue": "$1.11"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what json classes looks like:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new[] { node };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JObject> ObjectsOrSelf(this JToken root)
    {
        if (root is JObject)
            yield return (JObject)root;
        else if (root is JContainer)
            foreach (var item in ((JContainer)root).Children())
                foreach (var child in item.ObjectsOrSelf())
                    yield return child;
        else
            yield break;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> SingleOrMultiple(this JToken source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        IEnumerable<JToken> arr = source as JArray;
        return arr ?? new[] { source };
    }
}
```

Since someone asked for the original XML, here it is:

```
<DataFeed FeedName="issuerDetails">
<CompanyDetails></CompanyDetails>
<SecurityDetails minDisplayYear="2014" maxDisplayYear="2020">
<Security sequence="900" primaryIndicator="No">
<TimesSeriesList description="EPS" clientsDescription="EPS" id="1" qualifier="--" currencyName="CAD" currencySymbol="C$" fiscalId="1" fiscalCalendar="Fiscal" qualifierId="0">
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Actual" period="Q1" periodEnd="2015-12-31T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$0.45">0.4502</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Actual" period="Q2" periodEnd="2015-3-31T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$0.43">0.43</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Actual" period="Q3" periodEnd="2015-6-30T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$0.64">0.64</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Estimate" period="Q4" periodEnd="2015-9-30T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$0.52">0.52</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Estimate" period="Annual" periodEnd="2015-9-30T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$2.03">2.0325</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
<FinancialValue displayRank="900" estimateActual="Estimate" period="Q1" periodEnd="2016-12-31T00:00:00.00" displayName="EPS">
<CurrentValue displayValue="$0.56">0.56</CurrentValue>
</FinancialValue>
</TimesSeriesList>
</Security>
</SecurityDetails>
</DataFeed>
```

Here's what my code looks like for the JSON feed:

```
from securityDetail in jsonFeed
    .SelectTokens("DataFeed.SecurityDetails.Security.TimesSeriesList")
    .SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
let metric = securityDetail
     .SelectToken("@clientDescription")
     .SingleOrMultiple()
     .Select(t => (string)t)
     .ToArray()
where metric.Equals("EPS") && metric != null
let finValues = securityDetail.SelectTokens("FinancialValue")
    .SelectMany(d => d.ObjectsOrSelf())
orderby finValues.SelectToken("@periodEnd") descending  // <-- getting a error here
orderby finValues.SelectToken("@period") descending
select new 
{
    LastRptQtr = string.format("{0}{1}",
            (string)(finValues
                .SelectToken("@periodEnd").FirstOrDefault()).Substring(0, 4),
            (string)finValues
                .SelectToken("@period").FirstOrDefault()),
        DispVal = finValues
            .SelectToken("CurrentValue.@displayValue").FirstOrDefault()
}
```

In the end, I need:

```
LastRptQtr = "2015Q3"
DispVal = "$0.34"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
'IEnumerable<JObject>' does not contain a definition for 'SelectToken' 
and no extension method 'SelectToken' accepting a first argument of 
type 'IEnumerable<JObject>' could be found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the original xml? It may be easier to work with,

Comment: What does method ObjectsOrSelf do?

Comment: How do I fix my code to get it to work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

*if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail*. You don't need to convert your original xml to json. Working on original xml will be simpler.

Using Linq2Xml + Xpath

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var elements = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@periodEnd and (@clientsDescription='EPS' or @displayName='EPS')]")
                .OrderBy(x => (DateTime)x.Attribute("periodEnd"))
                .Select(x=>new {
                    PeriodEnd = (DateTime)x.Attribute("periodEnd"),
                    DispVal = (string)x.Element("CurrentValue").Attribute("displayValue")
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Working on the original XML seems to be more quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this pretty easily with Json.Net.

Given the following json string.

```
var json = @"
{
    ""?xml"": {
        ""@version"": ""1.0"",
        ""@encoding"": ""UTF-8""
    },
    ""DataFeed"": {
        ""@FeedName"": ""issuerDetails"",
        ""SecurityDetails"": {
            ""Security"": {
                ""@sequence"": ""850"",
                ""TimesSeriesList"": [{
                        ""@description"": ""EPS"",
                        ""@clientsDescription"": ""EPS"",
                        ""FinancialValue"": [{
                                ""@displayRank"": ""850"",
                                ""@estimateActual"": ""Actual"",
                                ""@period"": ""Q1"",
                                ""@periodEnd"": ""2015-9-30T00:00:00.00"",
                                ""@displayName"": ""EPS"",
                                ""CurrentValue"": {
                                    ""@displayValue"": ""$0.19""
                                }
                            }, {
                                ""@displayRank"": ""850"",
                                ""@estimateActual"": ""Actual"",
                                ""@period"": ""Q2"",
                                ""@periodEnd"": ""2015-12-31T00:00:00.00"",
                                ""@displayName"": ""EPS"",
                                ""CurrentValue"": {
                                    ""@displayValue"": ""$0.26""
                                }
                            }, {
                                ""@displayRank"": ""850"",
                                ""@estimateActual"": ""Actual"",
                                ""@period"": ""Q3"",
                                ""@periodEnd"": ""2015-3-31T00:00:00.00"",
                                ""@displayName"": ""EPS"",
                                ""CurrentValue"": {
                                    ""@displayValue"": ""$0.34""
                                }
                            }, {
                                ""@displayRank"": ""850"",
                                ""@estimateActual"": ""Estimate"",
                                ""@period"": ""Q4"",
                                ""@periodEnd"": ""2015-6-30T00:00:00.00"",
                                ""@displayName"": ""EPS"",
                                ""CurrentValue"": {
                                    ""@displayValue"": ""$0.32""
                                }
                            }, {
                                ""@displayRank"": ""850"",
                                ""@estimateActual"": ""Estimate"",
                                ""@period"": ""Annual"",
                                ""@periodEnd"": ""2015-6-30T00:00:00.00"",
                                ""@displayName"": ""EPS"",
                                ""CurrentValue"": {
                                    ""@displayValue"": ""$1.11""
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}";
```

The following appears to do what you want:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj["DataFeed"]["SecurityDetails"]["Security"]["TimesSeriesList"]
.Where(x => 
    x.HasValues 
    && x["@clientsDescription"].Value<string>() == "EPS")
.SelectMany(x => x["FinancialValue"].Children())
.Where(x => x["@estimateActual"].Value<string>() == "Actual")
.Select(x => new { 
    PeriodEnd = x["@periodEnd"].Value<DateTime>(), 
    Period = x["@period"].Value<string>(), 
    DisplayValue = x["CurrentValue"]["@displayValue"].Value<string>(),
    LastReportQuarter = x["@periodEnd"].Value<DateTime>().Year.ToString() + x["@period"].Value<string>()})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.PeriodEnd.Year)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Period)
.First()
.Dump();
```

> PeriodEnd 3/31/2015 12:00:00 AM 
>   Period Q3 
>   DisplayValue $0.34 
>   LastReportQuarter 2015Q3

Answer (score 0):

The method `ObjectsOrSelf` returns `IEnumerable`, 
then in the clause `let a = data.SelectMany(t=>t.ObjectsOrSelf())` variable `a` has type IEnumerable and it needs to be expanded by `from b in a`.

```
var result = from securityDetail in obj.SelectTokens("DataFeed.SecurityDetails.Security.TimesSeriesList").SelectMany(t => t.ObjectsOrSelf())
    let metric = securityDetail.SelectToken("@clientsDescription")
    where metric != null && metric.Value<String>() == "EPS"
    let finValues = securityDetail.SelectTokens("FinancialValue").SelectMany(d => d.ObjectsOrSelf())
    from v in finValues
    orderby v.SelectToken("@periodEnd") descending
    orderby v.SelectToken("@period") descending
    select new
    {
        LastRptQtr = string.Format("{0}{1}",
            ((string) v.SelectToken("@periodEnd")).Substring(0, 4),
            (string) v.SelectToken("@period")),
        DispVal = v.SelectToken("CurrentValue.@displayValue").Value<String>()
    };
```